# How to add text inside the padding of an image

Tags: padding

Is it possible to have text inside of the padding of an image. Here is my code now. The text appears under the padding of the image.

HTML

```
 <div>
 <img class="icon" src="Computer Icon.png" height="145">
 <p>Simple HTML Websites</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .icon {
 padding: 40px 80px 220px;
 background-color: #afafaf;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 150px; 
   width: 100%; 
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/flower_bouquet_leaf_221397.jpg" alt="" />
      
      <h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.icon1` is fancy.

`.icon2` is less fancy.

`fit-content` is a very little known property that is very handy for fitting an element over content. See [**ARTICLE**](http://thenewcode.com/975/Little-Big-Using-CSS-fit-content)

The properties of `icon2` are fundamental.

Using `figure` and `figcaption` instead of `div` and `p` makes no difference. You'll get the same results, but using the former is more semantic.

**EDIT**

If you meant by *inside image padding* meaning kind of like text superimposed on an image, then try `.icon3`. It utilizes the `position` property. See [**ARTICLE**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

```css
.icon1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 165px;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  font: 400 16px/1.4'Source Code Pro';
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #103683;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.icon2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  padding: 10px;
}
.icon3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 145px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  padding: 10px;
}
.icon1 img,
.icon2 img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.icon3 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 72.5px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.icon1 figcaption,
.icon2 figcaption {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon3 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="icon1">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/53/workstation-150503_640.png" height="145" width="145">
  <figcaption>Simple HTML Websites</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="icon2">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/53/workstation-150503_640.png" height="145" width="145">
  <figcaption>Simple HTML Websites</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="icon3">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/53/workstation-150503_640.png" height="145" width="145">
  <figcaption>Simple HTML Websites</figcaption>
</figure>
```